# csv-mode is very slow

Tags: spacemacs, performance, csv

Just about any buffer with csv-mode enabled gets very slow/unresponsive, regardless of how big the file is. It takes up to half a second to jump to the next line/character. Any idea why that is?

I use Spacemacs 0.200.9@24.5.1

I also had to change the varibale `csv-seperator` to `;` since this is the seperator in my files.

Here is an example:

```
;preposition;Example;regular/irregular;Presente;;;;;;Pretérito Perfeito;;;;;;Pretérito Imperfeito;;;;;;Pretérito mais-que-perfeito;;;;;;Futuro do Presente;;;;;;Subjuntivo Presente;;;;;;Subjuntivo Pretérito Imperfeito;;;;;;Subjuntivo Futuro;;;;;;Infinitivo Pessoal;;;;;;Futuro do Pretérito;;;;;;Imperativo Afirmativo;;;;;Imperativo Negativo;;;;;Gerúndio;Particípio passado
;;;;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;eu;tu;você;nós;vós;eles;tu;ele;nós;vós;eles;tu;ele;nós;vós;eles;;
ser;;Eu sou uma pessao honesta.;I;sou;és;é;somos;sois;são;fui;foste;foi;fomos;fostes;foram;era;eras;era;éramos;éreis;eram;fora;foras;fora;fôramos;fôreis;foram;serei;serás;será;seremos;sereis;serão;seja;sejas;seja;sejamos;sejais;sejam;fosse;fosses;fosse;fôssemos;fôsseis;fossem;for;fores;for;formos;fordes;forem;ser;seres;ser;sermos;serdes;serem;seria;serias;seria;seríamos;seríeis;seriam;sê;seja;sejamos;sede;sejam;sejas;seja;sejamos;sejais;sejam;sendo;sido
estar;;O livro está em cima da mesa.;I;estou;estás;está;estamos;estais;estão;estive;estiveste;esteve;estivemos;estivestes;estiveram;estava;estavas;estava;estávamos;estáveis;estavam;estivera;estiveras;estivera;estivéramos;estivéreis;estiveram;estarei;estarás;estará;estaremos;estareis;estarão;esteja;estejas;esteja;estejamos;estejais;estejam;estivesse;estivesses;estivesse;estivéssemos;estivésseis;estivessem;estiver;estiveres;estiver;estivermos;estiverdes;estiverem;estar;estares;estar;estarmos;estardes;estarem;estaria;estarias;estaria;estaríamos;estaríeis;estariam;está;esteja;estejamos;estai;estejam;estejas;esteja;estejamos;estejais;estejam;estando;estado
ter;de;Eu tenho muitos amigos na California.;I;tenho;tens;tem;temos;tendes;têm;tive;tiveste;teve;tivemos;tivestes;tiveram;tinha;tinhas;tinha;tínhamos;tínheis;tinham;tivera;tiveras;tivera;tivéramos;tivéreis;tiveram;terei;terás;terá;teremos;tereis;terão;tenha;tenhas;tenha;tenhamos;tenhais;tenham;tivesse;tivesses;tivesse;tivéssemos;tivésseis;tivessem;tiver;tiveres;tiver;tivermos;tiverdes;tiverem;ter;teres;ter;termos;terdes;terem;teria;terias;teria;teríamos;teríeis;teriam;tem;tenha;tenhamos;tende;tenham;tenhas;tenha;tenhamos;tenhais;tenham;tendo;tido
ir;a/para/em;Você vai à praia agora?;I;vou;vais;vai;vamos;ides;vão;fui;foste;foi;fomos;fostes;foram;ia;ias;ia;íamos;íeis;iam;fora;foras;fora;fôramos;fôreis;foram;irei;irás;irá;iremos;ireis;irão;vá;vás;vá;vamos;vades;vão;fosse;fosses;fosse;fôssemos;fôsseis;fossem;for;fores;for;formos;fordes;forem;ir;ires;ir;irmos;irdes;irem;iria;irias;iria;iríamos;iríeis;iriam;vai;vá;vamos;ide;vão;vás;vá;vamos;vades;vão;indo;ido
vir;a/para/por/de;Eu venho da Europa.;I;venho;vens;vem;vimos;vindes;vêm;vim;vieste;veio;viemos;viestes;vieram;vinha;vinhas;vinha;vínhamos;vínheis;vinham;viera;vieras;viera;viéramos;viéreis;vieram;virei;virás;virá;viremos;vireis;virão;venha;venhas;venha;venhamos;venhais;venham;viesse;viesses;viesse;viéssemos;viésseis;viessem;vier;vieres;vier;viermos;vierdes;vierem;vir;vires;vir;virmos;virdes;virem;viria;virias;viria;viríamos;viríeis;viriam;vem;venha;venhamos;vinde;venham;venhas;venha;venhamos;venhais;venham;vindo;vindo
fazer;;Ele faz um bom trabalho.;I;faço;fazes;faz;fazemos;fazeis;fazem;fiz;fizeste;fez;fizemos;fizestes;fizeram;fazia;fazias;fazia;fazíamos;fazíeis;faziam;fizera;fizeras;fizera;fizéramos;fizéreis;fizeram;farei;farás;fará;faremos;fareis;farão;faça;faças;faça;façamos;façais;façam;fizesse;fizesses;fizesse;fizéssemos;fizésseis;fizessem;fizer;fizeres;fizer;fizermos;fizerdes;fizerem;fazer;fazeres;fazer;fazermos;fazerdes;fazerem;faria;farias;faria;faríamos;faríeis;fariam;faze;faça;façamos;fazei;façam;faças;faça;façamos;façais;façam;fazendo;feito
querer;+inf.;Eu quero comprar esse chocolate.;I;quero;queres;quer;queremos;quereis;querem;quis;quiseste;quis;quisemos;quisestes;quiseram;queria;querias;queria;queríamos;queríeis;queriam;quisera;quiseras;quisera;quiséramos;quiséreis;quiseram;quererei;quererás;quererá;quereremos;querereis;quererão;queira;queiras;queira;queiramos;queirais;queiram;quisesse;quisesses;quisesse;quiséssemos;quisésseis;quisessem;quiser;quiseres;quiser;quisermos;quiserdes;quiserem;querer;quereres;querer;querermos;quererdes;quererem;quereria;quererias;quereria;quereríamos;quereríeis;quereriam;quer;queira;queiramos;querei;queiram;queiras;queira;queiramos;queirais;queiram;querendo;querido
poder;+inf.;Ele pode me ajudar.;I;posso;podes;pode;podemos;podeis;podem;pude;pudeste;pôde;pudemos;pudestes;puderam;podia;podias;podia;podíamos;podíeis;podiam;pudera;puderas;pudera;pudéramos;pudéreis;puderam;poderei;poderás;poderá;poderemos;podereis;poderão;possa;possas;possa;possamos;possais;possam;pudesse;pudesses;pudesse;pudéssemos;pudésseis;pudessem;puder;puderes;puder;pudermos;puderdes;puderem;poder;poderes;poder;podermos;poderdes;poderem;poderia;poderias;poderia;poderíamos;poderíeis;poderiam;;;;;;;;;;;podendo;podido
conseguir;;Eu consigo andar de bicicleta.;I;consigo;consegues;consegue;conseguimos;conseguis;conseguem;consegui;conseguiste;conseguiu;conseguimos;conseguistes;conseguiram;conseguia;conseguias;conseguia;conseguíamos;conseguíeis;conseguiam;conseguira;conseguiras;conseguira;conseguíramos;conseguíreis;conseguiram;conseguirei;conseguirás;conseguirá;conseguiremos;conseguireis;conseguirão;consiga;consigas;consiga;consigamos;consigais;consigam;conseguisse;conseguisses;conseguisse;conseguíssemos;conseguísseis;conseguissem;conseguir;conseguires;conseguir;conseguirmos;conseguirdes;conseguirem;conseguir;conseguires;conseguir;conseguirmos;conseguirdes;conseguirem;conseguiria;conseguirias;conseguiria;conseguiríamos;conseguiríeis;conseguiriam;consegue;consiga;consigamos;consegui;consigam;consigas;consiga;consigamos;consigais;consigam;conseguindo;conseguido
saber;+inf.;Eu sei que ela está lá, na casa dele.;I;sei;sabes;sabe;sabemos;sabeis;sabem;soube;soubeste;soube;soubemos;soubestes;souberam;sabia;sabias;sabia;sabíamos;sabíeis;sabiam;soubera;souberas;soubera;soubéramos;soubéreis;souberam;saberei;saberás;saberá;saberemos;sabereis;saberão;saiba;saibas;saiba;saibamos;saibais;saibam;soubesse;soubesses;soubesse;soubéssemos;soubésseis;soubessem;souber;souberes;souber;soubermos;souberdes;souberem;saber;saberes;saber;sabermos;saberdes;saberem;saberia;saberias;saberia;saberíamos;saberíeis;saberiam;sabe;saiba;saibamos;sabei;saibam;saibas;saiba;saibamos;saibais;saibam;sabendo;sabido
conhecer;;Você conhece João?;R;conheço;conheces;conhece;conhecemos;conheceis;conhecem;conheci;conheceste;conheceu;conhecemos;conhecestes;conheceram;conhecia;conhecias;conhecia;conhecíamos;conhecíeis;conheciam;conhecera;conheceras;conhecera;conhecêramos;conhecêreis;conheceram;conhecerei;conhecerás;conhecerá;conheceremos;conhecereis;conhecerão;conheça;conheças;conheça;conheçamos;conheçais;conheçam;conhecesse;conhecesses;conhecesse;conhecêssemos;conhecêsseis;conhecessem;conhecer;conheceres;conhecer;conhecermos;conhecerdes;conhecerem;conhecer;conheceres;conhecer;conhecermos;conhecerdes;conhecerem;conheceria;conhecerias;conheceria;conheceríamos;conheceríeis;conheceriam;conhece;conheça;conheçamos;conhecei;conheçam;conheças;conheça;conheçamos;conheçais;conheçam;conhecendo;conhecido
sair;de/para;Você quer sair comigo?;I;saio;sais;sai;saímos;saís;saem;saí;saíste;saiu;saímos;saístes;saíram;saía;saías;saía;saíamos;saíeis;saíam;saíra;saíras;saíra;saíramos;saíreis;saíram;sairei;sairás;sairá;sairemos;saireis;sairão;saia;saias;saia;saiamos;saiais;saiam;saísse;saísses;saísse;saíssemos;saísseis;saíssem;sair;saíres;sair;sairmos;sairdes;saírem;sair;saíres;sair;sairmos;sairdes;saírem;sairia;sairias;sairia;sairíamos;sairíeis;sairiam;sai;saia;saiamos;saí;saiam;saias;saia;saiamos;saiais;saiam;saindo;saído
dizer;;Minha mãe me diz sempre para ter cuidado.;I;digo;dizes;diz;dizemos;dizeis;dizem;disse;disseste;disse;dissemos;dissestes;disseram;dizia;dizias;dizia;dizíamos;dizíeis;diziam;dissera;disseras;dissera;disséramos;disséreis;disseram;direi;dirás;dirá;diremos;direis;dirão;diga;digas;diga;digamos;digais;digam;dissesse;dissesses;dissesse;disséssemos;dissésseis;dissessem;disser;disseres;disser;dissermos;disserdes;disserem;dizer;dizeres;dizer;dizermos;dizerdes;dizerem;diria;dirias;diria;diríamos;diríeis;diriam;dize;diga;digamos;dizei;digam;digas;diga;digamos;digais;digam;dizendo;dito
ouvir;;Ele ouve muito rock.;I;ouço;ouves;ouve;ouvimos;ouvis;ouvem;ouvi;ouviste;ouviu;ouvimos;ouvistes;ouviram;ouvia;ouvias;ouvia;ouvíamos;ouvíeis;ouviam;ouvira;ouviras;ouvira;ouvíramos;ouvíreis;ouviram;ouvirei;ouvirás;ouvirá;ouviremos;ouvireis;ouvirão;ouça;ouças;ouça;ouçamos;ouçais;ouçam;ouvisse;ouvisses;ouvisse;ouvíssemos;ouvísseis;ouvissem;ouvir;ouvires;ouvir;ouvirmos;ouvirdes;ouvirem;ouvir;ouvires;ouvir;ouvirmos;ouvirdes;ouvirem;ouviria;ouvirias;ouviria;ouviríamos;ouviríeis;ouviriam;ouve;ouça;ouçamos;ouçais;ouçam;ouças;ouça;ouçamos;ouçais;ouçam;ouvindo;ouvido
sentir;;Eu sinto muito.;I;sinto;sentes;sente;sentimos;sentis;sentem;senti;sentiste;sentiu;sentimos;sentistes;sentiram;sentia;sentias;sentia;sentíamos;sentíeis;sentiam;sentira;sentiras;sentira;sentíramos;sentíreis;sentiram;sentirei;sentirás;sentirá;sentiremos;sentireis;sentirão;sinta;sintas;sinta;sintamos;sintais;sintam;sentisse;sentisses;sentisse;sentíssemos;sentísseis;sentissem;sentir;sentires;sentir;sentirmos;sentirdes;sentirem;sentir;sentires;sentir;sentirmos;sentirdes;sentirem;sentiria;sentirias;sentiria;sentiríamos;sentiríeis;sentiriam;sente;sinta;sintamos;senti;sintam;sintas;sinta;sintamos;sintais;sintam;sentindo;sentido
pedir;;Minha irmã sempre me pede dinheiro emprestado.;I;peço;pedes;pede;pedimos;pedis;pedem;pedi;pediste;pediu;pedimos;pedistes;pediram;pedia;pedias;pedia;pedíamos;pedíeis;pediam;pedira;pediras;pedira;pedíramos;pedíreis;pediram;pedirei;pedirás;pedirá;pediremos;pedireis;pedirão;peça;peças;peça;peçamos;peçais;peçam;pedisse;pedisses;pedisse;pedíssemos;pedísseis;pedissem;pedir;pedires;pedir;pedirmos;pedirdes;pedirem;pedir;pedires;pedir;pedirmos;pedirdes;pedirem;pediria;pedirias;pediria;pediríamos;pediríeis;pediriam;pede;peça;peçamos;pedi;peçam;peças;peça;peçamos;peçais;peçam;pedindo;pedido
perder;;Eu sempre perco esse ônibus.;I;perco;perdes;perde;perdemos;perdeis;perdem;perdi;perdeste;perdeu;perdemos;perdestes;perderam;perdia;perdias;perdia;perdíamos;perdíeis;perdiam;perdera;perderas;perdera;perdêramos;perdêreis;perderam;perderei;perderás;perderá;perderemos;perdereis;perderão;perca;percas;perca;percamos;percais;percam;perdesse;perdesses;perdesse;perdêssemos;perdêsseis;perdessem;perder;perderes;perder;perdermos;perderdes;perderem;perder;perderes;perder;perdermos;perderdes;perderem;perderia;perderias;perderia;perderíamos;perderíeis;perderiam;perde;perca;percamos;perdei;percam;percas;perca;percamos;percais;percam;perdendo;perdido
manter;;Eu mantenho meu quarto sempre limpo.;I;mantenho;manténs;mantém;mantemos;mantendes;mantêm;mantive;mantiveste;manteve;mantivemos;mantivestes;mantiveram;mantinha;mantinhas;mantinha;mantínhamos;mantínheis;mantinham;mantivera;mantiveras;mantivera;mantivéramos;mantivéreis;mantiveram;manterei;manterás;manterá;manteremos;mantereis;manterão;mantenha;mantenhas;mantenha;mantenhamos;mantenhais;mantenham;mantivesse;mantivesses;mantivesse;mantivéssemos;mantivésseis;mantivessem;mantiver;mantiveres;mantiver;mantivermos;mantiverdes;mantiverem;manter;manteres;manter;mantermos;manterdes;manterem;manteria;manterias;manteria;manteríamos;manteríeis;manteriam;mantém;mantenha;mantenhamos;mantende;mantenham;mantenhas;mantenha;mantenhamos;mantenhais;mantenham;mantendo;mantido
ler;;Ela lê a bíblia.;I;leio;lês;lê;lemos;ledes;leem;li;leste;leu;lemos;lestes;leram;lia;lias;lia;líamos;líeis;liam;lera;leras;lera;lêramos;lêreis;leram;lerei;lerás;lerá;leremos;lereis;lerão;leia;leias;leia;leiamos;leiais;leiam;lesse;lesses;lesse;lêssemos;lêsseis;lessem;ler;leres;ler;lermos;lerdes;lerem;ler;leres;ler;lermos;lerdes;lerem;leria;lerias;leria;leríamos;leríeis;leriam;lê;leia;leiamos;lede;leiam;leias;leia;leiamos;leiais;leiam;lendo;lido
cair;;O vaso caiu no chão.;I;caio;cais;cai;caímos;caís;caem;caí;caíste;caiu;caímos;caístes;caíram;caía;caías;caía;caíamos;caíeis;caíam;caíra;caíras;caíra;caíramos;caíreis;caíram;cairei;cairás;cairá;cairemos;caireis;cairão;caia;caias;caia;caiamos;caiais;caiam;caísse;caísses;caísse;caíssemos;caísseis;caíssem;cair;caíres;cair;cairmos;cairdes;caírem;cair;caíres;cair;cairmos;cairdes;caírem;cairia;cairias;cairia;cairíamos;cairíeis;cairiam;cai;caia;caiamos;caí;caiam;caias;caia;caiamos;caiais;caiam;caindo;caído
pôr;;Ela põe todas as suas moedas no cofrinho.;I;ponho;pões;põe;pomos;pondes;põem;pus;puseste;pôs;pusemos;pusestes;puseram;punha;punhas;punha;púnhamos;púnheis;punham;pusera;puseras;pusera;puséramos;puséreis;puseram;porei;porás;porá;poremos;poreis;porão;ponha;ponhas;ponha;ponhamos;ponhais;ponham;pusesse;pusesses;pusesse;puséssemos;pusésseis;pusessem;puser;puseres;puser;pusermos;puserdes;puserem;pôr;pores;pôr;pormos;pordes;porem;poria;porias;poria;poríamos;poríeis;poriam;põe;ponha;ponhamos;ponde;ponham;ponhas;ponha;ponhamos;ponhais;ponham;pondo;posto
ver;;Eu vejo dois pássaros no céu.;I;vejo;vês;vê;vemos;vedes;veem;vi;viste;viu;vimos;vistes;viram;via;vias;via;víamos;víeis;viam;vira;viras;vira;víramos;víreis;viram;verei;verás;verá;veremos;vereis;verão;veja;vejas;veja;vejamos;vejais;vejam;visse;visses;visse;víssemos;vísseis;vissem;vir;vires;vir;virmos;virdes;virem;ver;veres;ver;vermos;verdes;verem;veria;verias;veria;veríamos;veríeis;veriam;vê;veja;vejamos;vede;vejam;vejas;veja;vejamos;vejais;vejam;vendo;visto
haver;;Para todo problema há uma solução.;I;hei;hás;há;havemos;haveis;hão;houve;houveste;houve;houvemos;houvestes;houveram;havia;havias;havia;havíamos;havíeis;haviam;houvera;houveras;houvera;houvéramos;houvéreis;houveram;haverei;haverás;haverá;haveremos;havereis;haverão;haja;hajas;haja;hajamos;hajais;hajam;houvesse;houvesses;houvesse;houvéssemos;houvésseis;houvessem;houver;houveres;houver;houvermos;houverdes;houverem;haver;haveres;haver;havermos;haverdes;haverem;haveria;haverias;haveria;haveríamos;haveríeis;haveriam;;haja;hajamos;havei;hajam;hajas;haja;hajamos;hajais;hajam;havendo;havido
```

CPU-profiler-report:

```
+ linum-update-current                                           7635  77%
+ command-execute                                                1639  16%
+ ...                                                             380   3%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                                  68   0%
+ timer-event-handler                                              53   0%
+ winner-save-old-configurations                                   12   0%
+ yas--post-command-handler                                        10   0%
+ global-hl-line-highlight                                          8   0%
+ evil-repeat-post-hook                                             4   0%
+ sp--save-pre-command-state                                        4   0%
+ evil--jump-hook                                                   2   0%
```

Comment: (a) Show us an example file? (b) Use the CPU profiler to see what Emacs is spending time doing. See `C-h i g (elisp) Profiling`

Comment: alright, I've done that

Comment: Disable linum and next time, completely expand the profiler report with `C-u TAB`.

Comment: how many levels do you want me to expand?

Comment: @user430 in general you would expand *as many levels as necessary* in order to identify the thing which is taking an unreasonable amount of time. In this case it's clearly `linum` related, as 77% of the CPU time in that profile results from calls to `linum-update-current`. If you needed more detail, you would keep expanding that part of the tree until you identified the primary culprit. (Or, as @wasamasa pointed out, use `C-u TAB` to show *all* the information.) In this case we can see right away that disabling `linum-mode` is going to eliminate 3/4 of your CPU time.